# Synset function to include synonym in a list

Tags: python, loops, wordnet

I need to iterate over a list and add synonyms and hyponyms of the words back to the list. For example:

```
list_of_words = ["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy"]
list_of_words = list_of_words + list_of_words_synonyms + list_of_words_hypnonyms
```

I'm able to get the synonyms and hypnonyms for individual words, but need to iterate over a list of values.

```
s = wordnet.synset(word)[0]
```

needs to return a list with individual synonyms added to the original list.

Expected result is:
    list_of_words = ["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy", "hen", "cock"..other synonyms of bird, "clever", "intelligent", other synonyms of smart....and so on]

How can I get the synset function to iterate over the list_of_words and include these words in the list? I'm very new to text analysis. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(create this new answer rather than update my existing one, as the question has updated quite a lot)*

Finally understand what wordnet.sysets() returns by installing package "pattern" and doing a debugging. Here is the code that runs:

```
from pattern.en import wordnet

list_of_words = [u"bird", u"smart", u"cool", u"happy"]
list_of_words_synonyms = []
list_of_words_hypnonyms = []

for word in list_of_words:
    sts = wordnet.synsets(word)
    if len(sts):
        st = sts[0]
        list_of_words_synonyms.extend(st.synonyms)
        list_of_words_hypnonyms.extend(hs.senses[0] for hs in st.hyponyms())        

list_of_words = list_of_words + list_of_words_synonyms + list_of_words_hypnonyms
print(list_of_words)
```

Please notes:

1. the duplication is not considered. If removing duplication is a requirement, then you may use [sets.Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html?highlight=sets.set#sets.Set) instead of list
2. for each hypnonym, it has multiple senses. list_of_words_hypnonyms just includes the first one. If you want to include all of them, use below code to replace the corresponing line:
   `list_of_words_hypnonyms.extend(sense for hs in st.hyponyms() for sense in hs.senses)`
3. for adding hypononyms to list_of_words_hypnonyms, [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) is used

The result is:

```
[u'bird', u'smart', u'cool', u'happy', u'bird', u'smart', u'smarting', u'smartness', u'cool', u'dickeybird', u'cock', u'hen', u'nester', u'night bird', u'bird of passage', u'protoavis', u'archaeopteryx', u'Sinornis', u'Ibero-mesornis', u'archaeornis', u'ratite', u'carinate', u'passerine', u'nonpasserine bird', u'bird of prey', u'gallinaceous bird', u'parrot', u'cuculiform bird', u'coraciiform bird', u'apodiform bird', u'caprimulgiform bird', u'piciform bird', u'trogon', u'aquatic bird', u'twitterer']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: according to OP's comment. Output format has been changed.

<s>Suppose you want an output like this:</s>

```
result = [
    ["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy"],
    [["Synonym 1 of bird...", ...], ["Synonym 1 of smart...", ...], ["Synonym 1 of cool...", ...], ["Synonym 1 of happy...", ...]],
    ...
]
```

New output format:

```
["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy", "synonym of bird", "hyponym of bird", "synonym of smart"... ]
```

You can iterate through the original word list as below:

```
from pattern.en import wordnet

list_of_words = ["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy"]
original_length = len(list_of_words)

for word in list_of_words:
    s = wordnet.synsets(word)[0]

    # append synonyms list to the result
    list_of_words.append([s.synonyms])

    # append hyponyms list to the result
    list_of_words.append(s.hyponyms())
```

After the iteration, you can access the lists by:

```
for index in range(original_length):
    print 'Displaying word %s' % list_of_words[index]
    print 'Synonyms: %s' % str(list_of_words[index + original_length])
    print 'Hyponyms: %s' % str(list_of_words[index + original_length + 1])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But because of "s = wordnet.synsets('bird')[0]" for every word only synonym and hyponym of "bird" show up and synset doesnt accept a list. Any solution? Also i need the result as one list ["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy", "synonym of bird", "hyponym of bird", "synonym of smart"... ]

Comment: @Ashwin Code edited, feel free to comment if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick implementation. Don't worry much about fakesynsets, which is just a mockup of wordnet.synsets. You can directly check the code following this function.

```
def fakesynsets(word):
    from collections import namedtuple
    sysnset = namedtuple('sysnset', ['synonyms', 'hyponyms'])

    return [sysnset(synonyms = [word+'syn'+str(ii) for ii in range(1,3)], hyponyms = lambda : [word+'hyp'+str(ii) for ii in range(1,3)])]


list_of_words = ["bird", "smart", "cool", "happy"]
list_of_words_synonyms = []
list_of_words_hypnonyms = []

for word in list_of_words:
    s = fakesynsets(word)[0]
    list_of_words_synonyms.extend(s.synonyms)
    list_of_words_hypnonyms.extend(s.hyponyms())

list_of_words = list_of_words + list_of_words_synonyms + list_of_words_hypnonyms

print(list_of_words)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get the output as ['bird', 'smart', 'cool', 'happy', 'birdsyn1', 'birdsyn2', 'smartsyn1', 'smartsyn2', 'coolsyn1', 'coolsyn2', 'happysyn1', 'happysyn2', 'birdhyp1', 'birdhyp2', 'smarthyp1', 'smarthyp2', 'coolhyp1', 'coolhyp2', 'happyhyp1', 'happyhyp2']....birdsyn1 is not replaced by the actual synonym?

Comment: I don't understand your question here. could you please elaborate it? Do you mean when you replaced fakesynsets with wordnet.synsets, you didn't get the expected result?

Comment: And what's the type of  the return of wordnet.synsets('bird')? My understanding is that it is a list of objects, each of which has two fields - synonyms and hyponyms. And based on the plural form of the naming as well as the use in the question, synonyms is a list/tuple, and synonyms is a callable that returns a list/tuple. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Sorry didnt understand the replacement.  I have modified the code in the question. Can u please take a look and point it out?

Comment: The return of wordnet.synsets("bird") is as follows: 
['bird', 'smart', 'cool', 'happy', u'bird', u'bird', u'bird', u'bird', Synset(u'dickeybird'), Synset(u'cock'), Synset(u'hen'), Synset(u'nester'),.......The code is not adding the corresponding synonyms to the list.

Comment: @Ashwin, firstly you shouldn't update your question with my sample code, because this will confuse others and get the problem in your question lost. What you need to do is to update your question with 1) type of the return of wordnet.synsets and 2) your expected result

Comment: I have edited the question with the expected result.

Comment: @Ashwin, I created another answer. Please check it out